# Android App parses InputStream xml file but not url http request

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I'm new to Android programming and Stack Overflow. I've tried every example possible that I could find but nothing seems to work so I'm hoping I could obtain someone's expertise in this area. I'm creating a basic Android app, using Android Studio, which uses DOM to parse an XML file stored on a web server. At first, I got the app working using .xml file stored in my project's local asset folder, but the project requires the data to be parsed from a URL provided. I switched the InputStream to pull from the URL but the data is no longer visible on the Android app layout. There are not visible errors. Am I missing some other configuration here? See code provided. Thanks

```
'public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    try {
        //InputStream is = getAssets().open("emr.xml");
        InputStream is = new URL("http://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/jburris/emr.xml").openStream();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

        Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
        element.normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("emr");

                for (int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element2 = (Element) node;
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\nPatient : " + getValue("name", element2)+"\n");
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"ID : " + getValue("patientID", element2)+"\n");
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\nRX : " + getValue("medicine", element2)+"\n");
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"Dosage : " + getValue("dosage", element2)+"\n");
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"Remaining : " + getValue("refillsRemaining", element2)+"\n");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}

private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
    NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node node = nodeList.item(0);
    return node.getNodeValue();
}
```

}'

Comment: do you have the permission in your app to access the internet? do you have exception handling there and an exception? is there a logentry regarding to this which can help?

Comment: I added the remainder of my activity code. Also, I added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  to my AndroidManifest.xml, outside the application tags. Working on getting error logs together

Comment: Added android application logs

Comment: Removed logs. no longer receiving errors. BUILD SUCCESSFUL. Unfortunately, issue still occuring

Comment: in newer android version you have to grant the permission by asking the user. you can also try to set the permission for the app like you would do for a normal app in your device properties -> apps -> your-app -> permissions

Comment: Hi Henning, it says it has full network access. Also, I previously added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to my AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio